# Is it possible to localize a string inside cs file in WPF project using LocBalm method?

Tags: wpf, localization, globalization, locbaml

In our WPF plugin project we use [LocBaml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx) tool to localize UI. But now it is needed to localize a string inside a cs file:

```
ToolInfo.MenuCaption = "&Toggle console";
```

I've found some localization topics:

[WPF Localization - On-the-fly Language Selection](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/10/30/wpf-localization-on-the-fly-language-selection.aspx)

[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com/)

[WPF Localization Extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/)

It seems that for using these 3rd party tools it is needed to remove LocBalm implementation and write a new one.

Is it possible to stay with LocBaml tool and add a translation just for this string in cs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the custom localization is taking place only in codebehind (cs file(s)), there's no reason that I can see for it to not work with LocBaml.

You could always use a hack to use LocBaml for this localized string as well, something like this :

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="HiddenText" Name="HiddenText" Text="&Toggle console" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

And in codebehind :

```
ToolInfo.MenuCaption = HiddenText.Text;
```

This is kind of mildly awful, but you should be able to still localize the string with LocBaml this way.

Otherwise, you'll have to string together a separate system yourself - something with resource strings and a resource manager, most likely - or try to get one of the localization platforms to play nice with LocBaml.